# Reverse lookup not showing all

Tags: dns, cygwin, reverse-dns

In CYGWIN when using

```
dig www.serveralias.com +short
```

I receive the following answer:

```
www.servername.com
10.10.10.10
```

So far, so good. Now I am running

```
dig 10.10.10.10 +short
```

and receive nothing. When running

```
dig 10.10.10.10
```

without +short I only see information regarding query time, root name servers, etc.

My question is: How to use a dig-command (alternatively host or nslookup) to get CNAME and A-record returned when querying via IP address knowing that a recursive pointer exist?

Tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have missed the `-x` option to `dig`. With that, `dig` will take an IP address and auto-generate the correct `in-addr.arpa` or `ip6.arpa` PTR query for you.

Note that actually asking for `10.10.10.10` will not give you a useful answer, since that is an RFC1918 address, but I assume you only used that as an example.